# Multiple daily repeating notifications at their specific time between in their intervals

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

For my app, I should send notifications to user.

For example:

user set 3 notifications
12:00
18:00
08:00

I want to send each notification everyday until i cancel them individually. Notifications should be sent, even if the app is closed.

Main:

```
registerAlarm(12, 0, 1);
registerAlarm(18, 0, 2);
registerAlarm(8, 0, 3);
```

Main Methods:

```
 private PendingIntent registerAlarm(int hour, int minute, int id){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("NAME",id);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, id, intent,0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    System.out.println("SELAMLAR OLSUN ID MAIN: " + id);
    return pendingIntent;
}

private void cancelAlarm(int RSQ) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RSQ, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Alarm Reciever:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("com.demo.FirebaseMessagingReceiveService");
    notificationIntent.setClass(context, Main2Activity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    int id = Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("NAME"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("ONLINE QUIZ APP")
            .setContentText("HEY TRY TO SOLVE TODAY")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});

    context.startService(notificationIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra("NAME",id);
int id = Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("NAME"));

don't working, ignore them.